# If $N$ is a submanifold of $M$ and $\dim M=\dim N$ then $M=N$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I need to prove that:

*Let $M$ be a smooth n-dimensional manifold and $N$ a immersed submanifold of $M$. If $\dim M=\dim N$ then $M=N$*

By the First Isomorphism Theorem it is clear that $i_{*x}:T_xN\to T_xM$ is a bijection for all $x\in M$. From here, how can I prove that $M$ must be equal to $N$?

Comment: This is not true as stated. Are you assuming $M$ is connected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any non-empty open subset $U$ of $M$ is naturally an embedded (hence immersed) submanifold of $M$. And $\dim U=\dim M$.